# What is the Graph API to get teams private channel settings? Also to update the private channel settings?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am working with the Microsoft Graph API. I want to get the Teams Private channel settings using Graph API. Following API gives me the list of private channels and

> GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teams-id}/channels?$filter=membershipType](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteams-id%7D/channels?$filter=membershipType) eq 'private'

And then using the channel id of private channel, I can use the following API to get channel information.

> GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teams-d}/channels/{channel-d}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteams-d%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-d%7D)

But this does not returns the Private channel settings. I am not able to find any API for the same. Is there any way to do get this information?

Comment: Please check this example to update the Channel with moderation settings - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-patch?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-update-channel-with-moderation-settings. It is currently in Beta. Could you please let us know if this helps?

Comment: This is useful only for public channel and not for private channel.

Comment: Currently only this is possible that too in Beta version. Could you please help posting this feature at [Microsoft feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)